# Phasing genotyped data using shapeit: ERROR: Wrong ordering in physical positions

Tags: phasing

I am to phase my genotyped data with Shapeit (from ped or bed files) and I keep on getting this error message:

> ERROR: Wrong ordering in physical positions curr_pos=13915
> prev=157299737

Any idea on how to fix this?

---

From the website:

"SHAPEIT is a fast and accurate method for estimation of haplotypes (aka phasing) from genotype or sequencing data. "

https://mathgen.stats.ox.ac.uk/genetics_software/shapeit/shapeit.html

Comment: It appears that your SNPs aren't ordered correctly - can you post some of those lines from the .bim file? Also, it seems like you are using shapeit2. Unless you have a good reason, you should be using the most up to date version, shapeit4.